# Exchange 2003 encrypt external relay

Tags: exchange, postfix, exchange-2003, security

I have a **Postfix** server filtering emails for an **Exchange 2003** server. From the firewall, all incoming emails are routed through Postfix, gets filtered before it is delivered to the Exchange 2003 server. All outbound emails are relayed to the Exchange server first and then it gets relayed to the Postfix server then out to the internet.

Inside the network, I have Outlook clients connecting to the Exchange server via MAPI.

However, I have some users who are **outside the network** and are using the Exchange server to send out emails via port 25 (NAT redirection). These users use Outlook Express, Thunderbird, and various mobile devices. I want to change this to a non-standard port (e.g. 465) and use TLS/SSL to secure the communication between end-client and the server. How do I do this without changing any configuration for the users inside the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MAPI clients don't care how their email is sent out by the server.  All they know is that they have Outlook connected to Exchange and when they send an email it goes to the server for delivery.

Any changes you do to the outgoing server ports won't be noticed by the Outlook clients.  No config changes necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Essentially, what I need to is to create another virtual SMTP connector for the secured relay, right?

Comment: yep.  Hope it is working.

Comment: Yes! It worked! Created a new virtual SMTP service and used a different port and enabled SSL. Now, my users are using the new port without any problem.